# How to go about checking if Windows is running any untrusted drivers (programatically)

Tags: windows, digital-signature, kernel, driver

I want to enforce a rule that my program start only if, at the time it launches, there are no untrusted kernel drivers running. I'm aware and have already tested file signature verification using [WinVerifyTrust](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wintrust/nf-wintrust-winverifytrust) winapi function, which works great.

The issue is there a few dozen unsigned drivers as part of the Windows installation. According to [DriverView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/driverview.html) all of them indeed belong to Microsoft. As an example,
**afunix.sys** is not signed, while afd.sys on the right has a valid signature.

[image]

As a workaround to this problem, is there any way to *reliably* identify these unsigned drivers as belonging to the Windows installation, and thereby to ignore them?

Comment: This should be done by the OS itself. The requirement will be impossible to enforce if your application is targeting the client machines. Unsigned drivers are "the thing" in Windows.